# convert image to occupancy grid?

Tags: ros, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to convert image taken from camera to occupancy grid map ?
what i did till now is to :

1- i made this photo by paint  just a white area with black boarders to let the robot moves within it

[http://imgur.com/7ize04b](https://imgur.com/7ize04b)

2- create a .ymal file with the same name at the same dir with this content

```
image:map.png
resolution: 0.1
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
negate: 0
```

3- run the roscore

4- `rosrun map_server map_server map.yaml`

and nothing happens , i checked the published topics using `rostopic list` and nothing is published, please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229596/convert-image-to-occupancy-grid-?/) by [g-emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/26155/g-emad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `map_server` package can probably help : http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

Write a .yaml file as specified on the wiki page and try to run `rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml`

**Edit:** You have a typo in your yaml : the first line needs an additional space :
`image: map.png` instead of `image:map.png`. To prevent this kind of mistakes in the future, I suggest you look up how to enable syntax highlighting for yaml in your editor and/or use a [yaml validator](http://www.yamllint.com/) if you really have a doubt. But usually your yaml library will do most of the job.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g-emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/26155/g-emad/) on 2016-03-20**:
i did so, but the map_server halt at the waiting for the map state

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-03-20**:
Can you edit your post to add your procedure and the complete output of your commands ? You must explain what you have tried before people can help you.

**Comment by [g-emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/26155/g-emad/) on 2016-03-21**:
done please help

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-03-21**:
See my edit, you have a typo

**Comment by [g-emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/26155/g-emad/) on 2016-03-21**:
thanks it now works , i spent many days searching because of this space  :D